# My buttons on hover have a major delay because of background-image: url()?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm using a background-image and for some reason it's causing the buttons to have a major delay on hover. I'm new to programming so not sure exactly why. All other images are working just fine with a normal button hover. I got a few times an error in the console but then the error disappears randomly."Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" This makes no sense. All other images work fine so it cant be the folder or anything, right? Please help!

I tried putting the images in one main folder and then linking it with /images/name.png, etc. The images are not in any folder just directly in with the html and css.
Here is the HTML and CSS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-image"></div>
      <div class="content"><h1>Interactive Puzzles</h1>
        <button class="themes_btn">Show me themes</button>
        <button class="play_btn">Play now</button>
    </div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titan+One&display=swap');

:root{
  --theme-btn: rgba(46, 176, 236, 0.829);
  --play-btn: rgba(43, 189, 133, 0.829);
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  overflow-X: hidden;
}

.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  font-family: 'Titan One', cursive;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.705);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 100%;
}

.play_btn{
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color:var(--play-btn);
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.603);
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.play_btn:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.39);
}

.themes_btn{
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: var(--theme-btn);
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.603);
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: 20px
}

.themes_btn:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 87, 128, 0.438);
}

.main-image{
  background-image: url(main-image.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  opacity: 65%;
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the image? Or create a codepen or codesanbox which can reproduce your issue? I've tested your code with my own image locally. Everything works just as it should

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried to upload the image, but stack-overflow said it was too big. The image size is 3.95MB. Could that the reason for the hover delay? I thought there are websites with even bigger images than mine...

Comment: I made the image 20vh and 20vw and the btns work fine now. Was it seriously the image size? That's so dumb. I wanted the image to be 200vh so the user can scroll down with the image for more content...It does not make sense though because I've used full background videos before and it buttons worked fine.

Comment: It could be the problem. You can try using a different image or reducing its resolution so it's smaller and see if that helps